# Is there a way to decrypt Outlook Message ID in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: email, webhooks, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

If A sents an email to B, and then you connect to each one's Microsoft Graph API, there is one issue : the 'internetMessageId' is the same in A "Sent Emails" and B "inbox" BUT the Outlook Id ('Id') is different.

--> Is there a way to decode / detect in the Outlook Id the fact that it is the same email but seen from different mailboxes ?

Behind that relies a simple problem : if I subscribe to webhooks for all employees mailboxes of a company (let us say 1000 persons), and 1 person sends an email to the "all company" group. Then my server will get 1001 POST concerning this email. As the only information in the notification parameters are the Outlook Message Id, I am unable to detect that it is all about the same message. The only way is to make 1001 calls to the graph API to get the internetMessageId, and then filter on that basis. It seems really heavy and resource consuming. Is there a way to avoid that ? Whether it is from webhook side, from notification content, or from Outlook Message Id decoding ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `Id` is opaque. It isn't based on the internet message ID.

The Microsoft Graph API doesn't support adding fields to your notification payloads, but the Outlook REST API itself does. If you use the Outlook endpoint directly (`https://outlook.office.com/api/`), you can use a `$select` to get additional fields in the notification payload, using a feature we call "rich notifications".

Docs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations#subscribe-to-changes-in-my-mail-calendar-contacts-or-tasks

Your subscription request would look something like:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
  "Resource": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/mailfolders/Inbox/messages?$select=Subject,InternetMessageId",
  "NotificationURL": "https://mywebapp.contoso.com/notifications",
  "ChangeType": "Created,Deleted,Updated",
  "ClientState": "Message unread"
}
```

Then the notification would include a `ResourceData` object with the requested fields.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.Notification",
      "Id": null,
      "SubscriptionId": "NjkyM0MwM0MtREJERi00MUY5LTlCMkQtQkRFOTREOTlEQ0EwX0ZDQkY1RTIwLUI1M0UtNENEQS05MEQyLTQyMkNBOUI4MkE1Mg==",
      "SubscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2017-06-29T20:57:26.3294822Z",
      "SequenceNumber": 3,
      "ChangeType": "Created",
      "Resource": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('1b1a2064-54a3-4f6e-b187-c1388c69fc0c@c4dd2789-1144-4832-bfaa-87f9955f5ef6')/Messages('AAMkAGZjYmY1ZTIwLWI1M2UtNGNkYS05MGQyLTQyMmNhOWI4MmE1MgBGAAAAAACiItQsBUn9QIuhejMqYpj5BwBk23L_AKqTR5R9JLmwxOUMAAAAAAEMAABk23L_AKqTR5R9JLmwxOUMAAC1vTIkAAA=')",
      "ResourceData": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message",
        "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('1b1a2064-54a3-4f6e-b187-c1388c69fc0c@c4dd2789-1144-4832-bfaa-87f9955f5ef6')/Messages('AAMkAGZjYmY1ZTIwLWI1M2UtNGNkYS05MGQyLTQyMmNhOWI4MmE1MgBGAAAAAACiItQsBUn9QIuhejMqYpj5BwBk23L_AKqTR5R9JLmwxOUMAAAAAAEMAABk23L_AKqTR5R9JLmwxOUMAAC1vTIkAAA=')",
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAABk23L+AKqTR5R9JLmwxOUMAAC131Ep\"",
        "Id": "AAMkAGZjYmY1ZTIwLWI1M2UtNGNkYS05MGQyLTQyMmNhOWI4MmE1MgBGAAAAAACiItQsBUn9QIuhejMqYpj5BwBk23L_AKqTR5R9JLmwxOUMAAAAAAEMAABk23L_AKqTR5R9JLmwxOUMAAC1vTIkAAA=",
        "InternetMessageId": "<DM5PR20MB1417BF6C48A2C62E529021BF9EDD0@DM5PR20MB1417.namprd20.prod.outlook.com>",
        "Subject": "Testing this"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Jason, I tried but then the subscription is not accepted, causing a 400 "Bad resource". Query Parameters seems not to be supported but would be appreciated  ! Thanks for your support and let me know if you have another idea.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. `$select` isn't supported for the resource in Graph. However, if you use the Outlook endpoint directly, you can register for "rich notifications" that include this kind of data. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you Jason, but everything works perfectly well with graph endpoint. If I try to call an https://outlook.office.com/api/... endpoint, I get a 401 with an invalid token. What I don't understand is how to change that : my app is registered on apps.dev.microsoft, and I have the admin consent to for it to access all mailboxes. So at no place I did specify that it is graph or outlook rest endpoint I would use. Why the token is not valid for outlook rest endpoint ?

Comment: No problem. To get an Outlook endpoint-compatible token, you need to fully qualify the scopes in your auth request. So for example, `Mail.Read` for Graph becomes `https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph-outlook for more helpful info.

Comment: But where ? 1) In the apps.dev.microsoft, i cannot modify scopes manually. In the manifest ? But scopes don't appear clearly. 2) Or just when requesting the token ? In that case I tried without success. I send a POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token with 4 elements in the body : grant_type set to 'client_credentials', client_id, secret_id, and scope set to 'https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read'. It sends back a 'not valid value for scope property'.

Comment: Let me be specific : how to get an admin consent for all mailboxes of an organization working both with graph and outlook REST apis ?

Comment: I will post the question as it is far from the original topic !

Comment: Is there any way that this ID (mentioned in the above code that has value starting wiht "AAMkAGZjYmY1ZTIwLWI1M2UtNG" - can be retried from a MS Outlook App MailItem? through a VBA or Python code or VB.Net Code?